# Regression Analysis model

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression, model-selection

Objective is to predict a car's retail value based on the characteristics of mileage, make, model, engine size, interior style, and cruise control.

---

### Price

The price of the vehicle

---

### Cylinder

4,6,8

---

### Liter

How many liters the engine is

---

### Doors

4 or 2 door

---

### Cruise control

1 if the car has, 0 if it does not

---

### Leather

1 if the car has, 0 if it does not

---

### Make

Buick,
Cadillac,
Chevrolet,
Pontiac,
SAAB,
Saturn

---

### Model

Century,
Lacrosse,
Lesabre,
Park Avenue,
CST-V,
CTS,
Deville,
STS-V6,
STS-V8,
XLR-V8,
AVEO,
Cavalier,
Classic,
Cobalt,
Corvette,
Impala,
Malibu,
Monte Carlo,
Bonneville,
G6,
Grand Am,
Grand Prix,
GTO,
Sunfire,
Vibe,
9_3,
9_3 HO,
9_5,
9_5 HO,
9-2X AWD,
Ion,
L Series

---

### Trim

Sedan 4D,
CX Sedan 4D,
CXL Sedan 4D,
CXS Sedan 4D,
Custom Sedan 4D,
Limited Sedan 4D,
Special Ed Ultra 4D,
DHS Sedan 4D,
DTS Sedan 4D,
Hardtop Conv 2D,
LS Hatchback 4D,
LS Sedan 4D,
LT Hatchback 4D,
LT Sedan 4D,
SVM Hatchback 4D,
SVM Sedan 4D,
Coupe 2D,
LS Coupe 2D,
LS Sport Coupe 2D,
LS Sport Sedan 4D,
Conv 2D,
SS Sedan 4D,
LS MAXX Hback 4D,
LT MAXX Hback 4D,
MAXX Hback 4D,
LT Coupe 2D,
SS Coupe 2D,
GXP Sedan 4D,
SE Sedan 4D,
SLE Sedan 4D,
GT Sedan 4D,
GT Coupe 2D,
GTP Sedan 4D,
AWD Sportwagon 4D,
GT Sportwagon,
Sportwagon 4D,
Linear Conv 2D,
Linear Sedan 4D,
Aero Conv 2D,
Aero Sedan 4D,
Arc Conv 2D,
Arc Sedan 4D,
Arc Wagon 4D,
Linear Wagon 4D,
Aero Wagon 4D,
Quad Coupe 2D,
L300 Sedan 4D

---

### Type

Sedan,
Convertible,
Hatchback,
Coupe,
Wagon

---

I was just wondering how I should set up a model for this data set?

This is what I was thinking so far:

Model (dummy variables for Doors, Cylinder, Make, Model, Trim, and Type)

Price = Mileage + Make_bui + Make_Cad+Make_Che + Make_Pon + Make_Saa + Make_Sat + Cylinder + Liter + Doors + Cruise + Leather

Comment: You might want to also look at Year/Age of the car?

Comment: In econometrics, this approach is called hedonic models. That should help narrow you search of the literature.

Comment: DanTheMan - the cars are all the same year